# How to create an array for a CPT post ID to use in an IF/WHILE statement

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields

I am using ACF and I am trying to do the following on a page

1. Create an array of the custom post type "Services" post IDs
2. Check if the array has at least 1 post ID
3. If so, for each post ID, display: `<?php the_field('the_field','POST_ID');?>`
4. If not, echo "There are no services"

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `fields` parameter of `WP_Query` to get just IDs back, then iterate over them with a `foreach` loop:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'services',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'fields' => 'ids',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $query->have_posts() ){
    foreach( $query->posts as $id ){
        the_field( 'the_field', $id );
    }
} else {
    echo 'There are no services';
}
```